# php multiple array edit

Tags: php, arrays

how can I edit "wind" array? For example, I want speed to be "3"?

```
$forecast = [
  "temperature" => "",
  "precipitation" => array("min-value", "max-value"),
  "wind" => [
    "speed" => "",
    "side" => "",
  ]
];
```

Comment: you need to set `$forecast['wind']['speed'] = 3;` or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the array by the next methods:

```
$forecast['temperature'] = 100500
$forecast['wind']['speed'] = 3
```

also you can get data from array:

```
$temperature = $forecast['temperature'];
$speed = $forecast['wind']['speed']
```